# Java, problems with Action Listener

Tags: java, actionlistener

I have looked on the internet and can not find any help with understanding action listeners. I am just starting to learn Java and I have yet to find a good tutorial that helps me understand how to use action listeners. Could someone look over my code or point me in the way of a useful tutorial explaining how to use action listeners?

```
public static void go implements ActionListener(){
    JFrame j = new JFrame();
    j.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    j.setSize(640,480);

    final Screen screen = new Screen();
    j.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, screen);

    JButton button = new JButton("Click Me!");
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

        public void ActionPerformed(Event e){
            screen.repaint();

        }

    });
    j.add(BorderLayout.NORTH, button);

    j.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: It will help you find an answer if you tag your question with `swing` or `java swing` (not sure which one is already present in SO, probably both)

Comment: _Alright, I have looked on the internet and can not find any help with understanding action listeners_ I can't simply believe this Use    **GOOGLE**, **SOF**....

Comment: It sounds like you are _very_ new to Java. That's OK. I suggest you work through Oracle's tutorial documentation. It's all online, and will answer many questions that you are likely to think of. One of those questions that the tutorials handle is how to handle GUI actions. **A simple web search for “Java Tutorial” will get you started.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other way and much better way is to use Anonymous class. You don't need to implement ActionListener

```
public static void go(){    // no need to implement actionListener
    JFrame j = new JFrame();
    j.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    j.setSize(640,480);

    final Screen screen = new Screen();
    j.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, screen);

    JButton button = new JButton("Click Me!");
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){ // change are made here

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {  //& here
            screen.repaint();
        }
    });
    j.add(BorderLayout.NORTH, button);
    j.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This got rid of the errors and fixed it... However now I have a new problem XD when I click the button screen doesn't respray... but when I maximize the window it does XD oh well...

Comment: @user3317264 that should be posted on another question.

Comment: +1 for anonymous classes. So much neater and logical than private classes or the horror that is trying to work out what source `e` was called from..

Comment: for your new problem @MagnusCaligo I need your full code to solve your problem....

Answer (score 0):

`actionPerformed` is a method of interface, its not a class.

So use actionPerformed insted of ActionPerformed and use annotation @Ovveride for ovveriding the actionPerformed to provide your own defination.

```
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            screen.repaint();
        }
```